# Magento 2.2.4 : product image not display

Tags: product-images, magento2.2.4

After upgrade magento to version 2.2.4, There are one issue generated that in product page image not display.

One more thing, I have display error in console when image loading.

> SyntaxError : JSON.parse : unexpected character at line .. column .. of the JSON Data.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be generated because of overriding `gallery.phtml` file by any third party module or third party theme.

You need to modify the `gallery.phtml` that is overridden by the third party module or theme.

```
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "[data-gallery-role=gallery-placeholder]": {
            "mage/gallery/gallery": {
                "mixins":["magnifier/magnify"],
                "magnifierOpts": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getMagnifier() ?>,
                "data": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getGalleryImagesJson() ?>,
                "options": {
                    "nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/nav") ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/loop"))): ?>
                        "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/loop") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/keyboard"))): ?>
                        "keyboard": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/keyboard") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/arrows"))): ?>
                        "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/arrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen"))): ?>
                        "allowfullscreen": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/allowfullscreen") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/caption"))): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/caption") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "width": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width') ?>",
                    "thumbwidth": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width') ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width')): ?>
                        "thumbheight": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_small', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height') || $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width')): ?>
                        "height": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'height')
                        ?: $block->getImageAttribute('product_page_image_medium', 'width'); ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/duration") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/transition/effect") ?>",
                    <?php if (($block->getVar("gallery/navarrows"))): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navarrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navtype") ?>",
                    "navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/navdir") ?>"
                },
                "fullscreen": {
                    "nav": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/nav") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop")): ?>
                        "loop": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/loop") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navdir": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navdir") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/transition/navarrows")): ?>
                        "navarrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navarrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "navtype": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/navtype") ?>",
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows")): ?>
                        "arrows": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/arrows") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption")): ?>
                        "showCaption": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/caption") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php if ($block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration")): ?>
                        "transitionduration": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/duration") ?>,
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    "transition": "<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getVar("gallery/fullscreen/transition/effect") ?>"
                },
                "breakpoints": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getBreakpoints() ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Clear cache and refresh the product page.

Answer (score 1):

In **gallery.phtml** replace

```
"arrows": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>,

"showCaption": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>,
```

with:

```
"arrows": '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/arrows"); ?>',

"showCaption": '<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getVar("gallery/caption"); ?>',
```